# CKEditor inline - cannot add form tag

Tags: ckeditor

We are not able to add the form tag to the inline [CKEditor](http://www.ckeditor.com) from chrome and IE, but it works fine in firefox. If we add the form to the inline CKEditor, its removing the form tag.

For ex.: If I add form tag in firefox, it adds as (which is working fine)

```
<form>Test</form>
```

[image]
But in IE and Chrome, it shows only: (this is where i have the issue)

```
Test
```

[image]
Any workaround for this?

Comment: Update to the latest CKEditor. Generally speaking, CKEditor 3.x is no longer supported and 4.x line fixes lots of issues.

Comment: oleq, I am using the latest version 4.1.2 for my application which is having this issue.

Comment: It totally works for me. Editor is returning `<form>Test</form>`. What is the context of your editor (what is the parent?)? When does editor remove the `<form>` tag (precisely)? What is the config for your editor?

Comment: @oleq, got the issue now. This is because i had the form tag for the page and the inline editor is inside it which is causing the issue. IE and Chrome are validating and remove the inner form if a form is placed inside a form, but Firefox is missing that. After I removed the form tag for the page, now i am able to add the forms inside the inline CKEditor.

Comment: Close the question then. You can answer own question and mark it as solved ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution for this. Its because of form tag in my page. When a form is added inside a form, IE and chrome seems to remove the added form tag. But Firefox ignores it. After i removed the main form tag of the page, it works fine in all browsers.

Comment: Wait, so you can't use ckeditor in a form if you want to be able to enter forms in the editor. That's awful.

Comment: @PixMach you can, you just need to switch the editor to the IFrame (as opposite to Inline) mode.